# How to set validation in multi-drop down with one element being set by default in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

I have this code where I have to add a validation that whether 'ALL' option is displayed on multi drop down menu although all other elements will also be available in drop down menu or if some other element is selected from drop down then 'ALL' option will automatically be removed but will be available in drop down. Precisely, either 'ALL' or others get selected in multi drop down .
I am a bit new to jquery.
This is what I am trying:

```
$('#selectPlayerDropDown').change( function() {
                console.log($(this).val()+"tttttt");
                console.log($(this).val()=='ALL')
                 var sel = $('#selectPlayerDropDown').val();
                 if(jQuery.inArray( "ALL", sel)){
                     console.log("Well Well");
                     //sel.find("option:sel(0)").remove();  
//                   $('#selectPlayerDropDown').children('option:not(:first)').detach();
                 }
                 console.log(sel+"///////////");

            });
```

Here's the original code

```
if( $.scoreType == 'PLAYER') {
            $(".selectPrintOnSingleOrMultiplePage").addClass('hide');
            $('#printForAllPlayersDiv').addClass('hide');
            $('#selectPlayerDropDown').find('option').remove().end();
            $('#selectPlayerDropDown').append($('<option>', {
                value : 'ALL',
                text : 'All'
            }));
            $('#printOrderSelection').removeClass('hide');
            $.each($.reservationAndPlayerData.playerData, function(index, object) {
                $('#selectPlayerDropDown').append($('<option>', {
                    value : index,
                    text : object
                }));

            });

            $(".player").removeClass('hide');
            $(".selectPracticeCar").addClass('hide');
            $('#selectPlayerDropDown').val('ALL').trigger('chosen:updated');
        }
```

HTML CODE:

```
<div class=" player hide col-md-12 row">
                            <label for="select-players" class="col-md-6"
                                th:text="#{label.competition.score.player.select}">Select
                                players</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <fieldset class="form-group">
                                    <select class="form-control chosen-select"
                                        id="selectPlayerDropDown" name="playerIds"
                                        data-placeholder="Choose players ..." multiple="multiple">
                                    </select> <label
                                        class="jqueryValidationErrorClass selectPlayerDropDownLabel hide"
                                        id="player-error" th:text="#{label.competition.player.choose}">Choose
                                        Players</label>
                                </fieldset>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Please post your html code too

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar Added the Html code

Comment: please check the anwer i have posted

Answer (score 0):

Try below code where you can check if ALL is selected or not and remove the ALL value from array of selected values of the dropdown.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#selectPlayerDropDown').on('change', function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        if(value!='ALL' && value.indexOf('ALL')>-1) {
          var index = value.indexOf('ALL');
          if (index > -1) {
            value.splice(index, 1);
          }
          $(this).val(value);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=" player hide col-md-12 row">
  <label for="select-players" class="col-md-6"
         th:text="#{label.competition.score.player.select}">Select
                                players</label>
  <div class="col-md-6">
      <fieldset class="form-group">
         <select class="form-control chosen-select"
                 id="selectPlayerDropDown" name="playerIds"
                 data-placeholder="Choose players ..." multiple="multiple">
                 <option>ALL</option>
                 <option>Player 1</option>
                 <option>Player 2</option>
                 <option>Player 3</option>
         </select>
         <label                             class="jqueryValidationErrorClass selectPlayerDropDownLabel hide"
         id="player-error" th:text="#{label.competition.player.choose}">Choose Players</label>
       </fieldset>
   </div>
 </div>
```